# python + escape for loop

Tags: linux, python

in my linux machine I have python script , and the relevant lines are:

```
        for cont in tmp:
            allConts.append(cont[0])
```

how to change add the rule - that for loop will escape to do allConts.append(cont[0]) in case cont variable is null ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `if cont` to determine that `cont` is not `None` or an empty list (python's null):

```
for cont in tmp:
    if cont:
        allConts.append(cont[0])
```

Comment: Indeed, my comment was too automatic, sorry :-)